# Send JMS Messages Synchronously

Tags: java, jms

Let's say I have a very simple JMS setup with a message producer

```java
@Stateless
public class MessageProducer {

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:global/jms/MyFirstJmsQueue")
    private Destination myFirstJmsQueue;

    public void sendMessage(String messageToSend) {
        this.context.createProducer().send(this.myFirstJmsQueue, messageToSend);
        System.out.println("SEND MESSAGE: " + messageToSend);
    }
}
```

And a message consumer:

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:global/jms/MyFirstJmsQueue")})
public class MessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + message.getBody(String.class));
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything is good and well. The finished product should work with a queue asynchronously.

BUT the **tests** shouldn't. To test that the setup works correctly, I need the tests to configure these classes to work synchronously.

Alternatively the classes can stay asynchronously, but the tests need to add something that says "wait until all messages are sent".

Is either of these options possible with JMS?

**Note:**

- Funnily enough I found `JMSProducer#setAsync` with JavaDoc saying "Calls to  send are synchronous by default.". Which obviously doesn't mean that receiving the message is synchronous, too.
- `JMSContext.createConsumer(this.myFirstJmsQueue).receive()` is not ideal either, because I wouldn't be able to test my setup, but if JMS works

Comment: The tests should use the same modes as the production code. Otherwise they aren't tests at all.

Comment: @user207421 That's what I'm saying. Still I'm not testing JMS but my code, so I don't need to test whether a hypothetical flag "isSynchronous" of JMS works correctly.

Comment: It is the iopposite of what you are saying.

Comment: @user207421 Sure, if you say so. What about my question? Is it possible to send messages synchronously or wait for a queue to empty?